# opening .wrl files

Tags: 12.10

I am working with ubuntu 12.10.

I am creating VRML (.wrl) files with a C program and they can be easily open with MeshLab.  Now, I want to open .wrl files with MeshLaB automaticly. How can I do that?

By right clicking myfile.wrl and trying

> Open with another application...

I get:

> No applications available to open "myfile.wrl"

Comment: view3dscene. works in nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

From that menu that you said (`No applications available to open "myfile.wrl"`) there is an option to search for applications.